# Executing shell commands with execvp()

Tags: c++, linux, shell, command

I want to write a program which acts like a Linux shell. I started with writing a small program to execute the "ls" command. What I can't figure out is how should I proceed in order to make my program respond to any command like the shell does. ( e.g cat, cd, dir).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 32
using namespace std;

int main() {
    pid_t c; 
    char s[MAX];
    int fd[2];
    int n;

    pipe(fd);
    c = fork();

    if(c == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
        return 0;
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        while( (n = read(fd[0], s, MAX-1)) > 0 ) {
            s[n] = '\0';
            cout<<s;
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make my program read what the user types in and passes it to `execlp` (or something similar that does the same thing)?

Comment: _"... to make my program respond to any command ..."_ In the parent process you have the `fd[1]` file descriptor, that you can use to write something on the established `pipe()`. Note the commands you have listed don't need any interaction from input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell basically does the following :

1. reads a line from stdin
2. parses that line to make a list of words
3. forks
4. then the shell (parent process) waits until the end of the child, while the child execs to execute the code of the command represented by the list of words extracted from the input line.
5. the shell then restarts at step 1.

Construct first a very simple shell.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand a problem, You can:

- read array of strings with `scanf()`
- run it as a command with `execvp()` (it works the same as `execlp()`, but You can pass all arguments as an array).

Something like:

```
char args[100][50];
int nargs = 0;
while( scanf( " %s ", args[nargs] ) )
   nargs++;
args[nargs] = NULL;
/* fork here *
...
/* child process */
execvp( args[0], args );
```